# quote table names in squeryl

Tags: scala, squeryl

I have a table named group in a mysql db. When I map this table to squeryl I get SQL syntax errors since the table name group is not quoted (should be select * from `group`).

Is there any way I can tell squeryl to quote certain table names?

Answer (score 2):

GROUP is a reserved word in SQL, so I'd recommend renaming your table to something else. (I'm guessing this is the cause of this issue.)

Comment: absolutely, therefore I need to quote the name.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried :

```
val groups = table[Group]("`group`")
```

?